# Why isn't wamp starting? (there's no apache logs)

Tags: windows, wamp, windows-8.1, wampserver

I installed wamp on windows 8.1 and it's not starting. Apache, mysql and php, none of it has started. I checked my antivirus and antikeylogger and it's not being blocked. When I check the apache error log and apache access log, it says that the log files do not exist. Without a log file, how do I troubleshoot the error?

Comment: You're not running Skype or anything else on port 80?

Comment: @Derp Skype isn't running and there's nothing running on port 80.

Comment: @Derp I fixed it now. I was trying to run a 32 bit on a 64 bit.

Comment: The 32bit WAMPServer should run quite happily on a 64bit Windows. 64bit Windows runs 32 bit code. But you do have to make sure you install all the [MSVC runtime libraries for both 64bit and 32bit](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295). There are still good reasons for running the 32bit WAMPServer as some PHP Extensions are still not yet converted to 64bit.

Comment: When the Apache or MySQL logs are empty, you should check the Windows Event Viewer for error messages as both write to the event log before they write to their individual log files and serious errors are likely to be recorded there